# strip_tags function not working for <p> something</p>

Tags: php, strip-tags

i have a input like this

```
$desc = &lt;p&gt;\r\n test job description!&lt;/p&gt;
```

i have used `echo  html_entity_decode(nl2br($desc),ENT_NOQUOTES,"Utf-8");`

and out put becomes     `<p>\r\n test job description!</p>`

then used `echo html_entity_decode(stripslashes(nl2br($desc)),ENT_NOQUOTES,"Utf-8");`

& got  `<p> test job description!</p>`

& used `echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(stripslashes(nl2br($desc)),ENT_NOQUOTES,"Utf-8"));` to get output like `test job description!` but the output becomes `<p> test job description!</p>`

what i am doing wrong here or what function i can use to get desired output `test job description!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
$desc = "&lt;p&gt;\r\n test job description!&lt;/p&gt;";
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(stripslashes(nl2br($desc)),ENT_NOQUOTES,"Utf-8"));
```

Outputs

```
test job description!
```

Either the data in your question is wrong or the code you're trying out is wrong. Double check and post again please.